# Unable to set checked as a default - knockout checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, knockout.js

I'm new in knockout and I couldn't solve a little problem, which is to set a checkbox as a default selected.

HTML:

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="summary" type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-bind="checked: Summarise"/> 
        Summary 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Doc.Ready:

```
if (!viewModel) {
    viewModel = new ViewModel();
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("ParametersView"));
```

This returns unchecked checkbox when it gets called.

Comment: give `this.Summarise(true)` in your view modal . working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/22460/

Comment: @supercool is right. Your view should not be trying to drive the default values of your model. Get rid of the `checked="checked"` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

To set a check-box `checked` by default , simply we need to assign `true` to the observable which is binded to checked prop.

**View Model:**

```
var viewModel= {
    Summarise:ko.observable(true)
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**View :**

```
<input id="summary" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Summarise"/>
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/22461/)**

For documentation refer **[here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html)**

Comment: No , that's a  total different scenario and a another question for the  day . do make it marked . appreciate it , cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use a ko.observable(true) and then bind it to the imput with property checked: for explanation, see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) on knockout website.